# How to count the #of of items in a list without using python's method while ignoring the items that come after a certain item

Tags: python

This is our review homework for a test. I have absolutely no idea how to do it as I have been away for quite a while. If someone could tell me what I need to learn to be able to complete this task. 
The program will than output how many places you need to visit before LA dodgers stadium on the way. Places  that are visited after  La dodgers stadium don't count.  It must also output the number of places visited that have have names that are more than one word (ex. San Jose.)  The catch is that you must use a while loop in this case - you may not use python's find method.

Sample

```
>>> places= ["Home","In-n Out Burger", "John's house", "Santa Monica Pier", "Staples center",  "LA Dodgers stadium", "Home" ]
>>> placesCount(places)
6 places to LA dodgers stadium
5 with multi-word names
```

Comment: Lucky you. Python lists don't have a `find` method. I think you mean `index`?

Comment: This is a terrible style of teaching. Use of `while` is really inappropriate here (ie. teaching the wrong way). Are you allowed to use `for` at least?

Comment: @gnibbler are you sure the teacher actually required `while`? That may be OP's (mis)interpretation of the question. There are many good ways to solve this problem without `while` or `list.index`, though `list.index` is probably the Dutch way to do it. ;)

Comment: Yes, we must use a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
places= ["Home","In-n Out Burger", "John's house", "Santa Monica Pier", "Staples center",  "LA Dodgers stadium", "Home" ]

def placesCount(places):
    placesToGo = 0
    for i in range (len(places)):
        if places[i] == "LA Dodgers stadium":
            placesToGo = placesToGo + 1
            print placesToGo, "places to LA dodgers stadium"
        else:
            placesToGo = placesToGo + 1
def multiCount(places):
    spaces = 0
    multiWords = 0
    for j in range (len(places)):
        word = places[j]
        for characters in word:
            if characters == " ":
                spaces = spaces + 1
        if spaces != 0:
            multiWords = multiWords + 1
            spaces = 0
    print multiWords, "multi-word names"

placesCount(places)
multiCount(places)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: Complete answer below.

Unless I'm missing something, this is pretty straightforward:

```
>>> def placesCount(places):
    multi_word = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        place = places[count]
        if place == 'LA Dodgers stadium':
            break
        if ' ' in place:
            multi_word += 1
        count += 1
    return count + 1, multi_word + 1

>>> placesCount(places)
(6, 5)
```

Comment: @aIKid Serious? This is a QnA site meant to answer specific questions.

Comment: I mean, don't give the full solution, give hints instead. Hahaha

Comment: This is BS. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful"

Comment: @alKid, this has been discussed at length on meta. It's officially fine and encouraged to give complete answers.

Comment: @gnibbler it's fine, and not my downvote, but it's also [considered helpful not to give the complete answer for homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: Also, @KaranGoel, you could consider marking your answer as spoiler.

Comment: @kojiro, nice one. I personally only downvote answers that are downright wrong, and usually I'll give a comment why I think it's wrong (I'm not always right)

Comment: @gnibbler I will occasionally downvote answers that are technically correct in the very limited context of a poorly defined question, but likely to be wrong for many future visitors facing a similar problem. I too tend to leave a comment when I downvote.

Comment: How does the function check if something is multiword

Comment: `if ' ' in place` checks if the place is a multi-word phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Hints…

```
def placesCount(places):
    '''Given a list `places`, determine how many elements exist before "LA Dodgers stadium",
    and how many places have spaces in them. Don't use `list.index`.'''
    spaces = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(places):
        if val == 'LA Dodgers stadium':
            print ??? # What should we print here?
        if ' ' in val:
            # increment spaces
    print ??? # What should we print here?
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you know how to do in Python? It looks like you need to

1. write a function, that
2. takes a list as an argument, and
3. use a `while` loop to look at elements of the list,
4. test whether a place has spaces in it,
5. test whether a place is the LA dodgers stadium
6. know whether we've been to the LA dodgers stadium yet,
7. count how many things occur before that item in the list,
8. count how many places had multiple words,
9. prints those numbers with accompanying text.

Which of those do you not know how to do? Making a function, making a function that takes arguments, using a while loop, getting items from a list, testing whether a string has spaces in it, testing whether a string is the same as another string, remembering information by writing it to a variable, counting by assigning numbers to variables and making them bigger, printing strings and numbers to the screen?

Comment: I dont know the last 5 things.                                                   test whether a place is the LA dodgers stadium
know whether we've been to the LA dodgers stadium yet,
count how many things occur before that item in the list,
count how many places had multiple words,
prints those numbers with accompanying text.